# Local only, revision/version/source control

Tags: svn, git, version-control, mercurial

From what I've read: Subversion, Git, Mercurial, Bazaar are good version control software.
Subversion is a server based one.

But what is the best (and I *encourage* adding your own) system when the only requirements are:

- simplicity - single-user / local
- I want to "go back (and forward) in time"
- integrates well with Visual Studio 2010.

This will be used with C++ if that matters and maybe C# in the future. I don't really want it to be cluttered by server interface things that I'll never use. The backward and forward I suppose implies branching.

Comment: you are probably better off tagging this svn, git, mercurial, bazaar than C++, they are all language agnostic

Comment: whoops, for some reason an old question was cached whenever I clicked ask question, and I forgot to change the tags!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are thinking about SVN then choose Hg instead, it's much better at branching and is decentralized. SVN is not. GIT, on the other hand, is but a lot of people use it centralized anyway ([github](https://github.com/), for instance).

It does not really matter what language you're gonna write in.

If you want to use Hg with Visual Studio then perhaps [VisualHG](http://visualhg.codeplex.com/) is the thing for you.

Comment: Mercurial is a DVCS. I believe that it is better than git

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I choose Mercurial over SVN and GIT myself.

Comment: I think I do like the look of VisualHg

Answer (score 4):

Out of these, I would say Mercurial is your best bet. It is:

1. is well-supported on Windows, unlike git (historically)
2. is supported within Visual Studio (see the [list of tools](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/OtherTools))
3. handles merges better than svn (and make no mistake, you will eventually merge something)
4. requires marginally less setup than svn, as there's no notion of a "central" repository to set up.

Answer (score 4):

For visual studio integration AFAIK bazaar doesn't have any and git's is probably a bit behind the curve compared to svn ([visualSvn](http://www.visualsvn.com/) or [ankhSvn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/)) and [hg](http://visualhg.codeplex.com/) (certainly if you want [explorer integration](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) as well as vs)

This gives you a choice of mercurial or subversion. a DVCS or CVS. for a single developer there is not so much to choose here but personally I'd go for mercurial. svn lacks some useful features like [bisect](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#bisect) and is generally seen as poor at merging. hg will also allow you to more easily break out of single developer mode in the future, should you want to start to share your project with others.